# ListPlot3D of 2D array with embedded axis coordinates

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I've go data like this:

```
{ { "name", x1,  x2,  x3,  x4  },
  { y1,     a11, a12, a13, a14 },
  { y2,     a21, a22, a23, a24 },
  ....
}
```

where `aij` is the value of some data at point `(xi, yj)`.

What would be the most straightforward way to display such data as a 3D plot or 3D surface? Ditto when one of the labels scales logarithmically and the other one linearly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restructure the data:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {5, 5}];

x = data[[1, 2 ;; All]]

y = data[[2 ;; All, 1]]

a = data[[2 ;; All, 2 ;; All]]

coords = Flatten[#, 1]& @
  Table[{x[[i]], y[[i]], a[[i, j]]}, {i, 1, Length @ x}, {j, 1, Length @ y}]

ListPlot3D @ coords
```

[image]